# Independent events such that the union of every subsequence has full probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> Let $A_1$, $A_2$, ..., be independent events. Show that  $P\left(\bigcup\limits_{j=0}^\infty A_{i_j}\right)=1$ for every subsequence $1\le i_1\le i_2\le$ ... of integers if and only if $\liminf_{n\to \infty} P(A_n) \gt 0$.

I don't know how to deal with these subsequences (in fact, we have "for every subsequence", which makes it more difficult for me). Also, I have mostly encountered problems dealing with limsup. So this problem appears to be new altogether. Can someone please guide me through this?

Comment: The condition is not that the limit exists and is positive, but that the liminf is positive. // Nice problem. For a start, can you show that the series $\sum\limits_nP(A_{i_n})$ diverges for every subsequence $(i_n)$?

Comment: Yes. Because liminf is the largest number 'a' such that for any ε>0, there exists N such that after that N, all terms would be greater than b-ε. So each subsequence will eventually be greater than 0? (is this correct?)

Comment: If a=b, this is correct.

Comment: oh. Sorry. I meant a on both occasions

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=0$.
Then for each $n$ we can pick $i_n$ (as an increasing sequence) such that $P(A_n)<3^{-n}$. Then $P(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_{i_j})\le \sum_{j=1}^\infty 3^{-j}=\frac12<1$.

On the other hand assume $\liminf_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=c>0$.
Then for any finite subsequence of length $n$ we have $$P(\bigcup_{j=1}^nA_{i_j})=1-P(\bigcap_{j=1}^n\overline{A_{i_j}})=1-\prod_{j=1}^ n(1-P(A_{i_j}))\ge1-(1-c)^n$$
Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$, we see that $P(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_{i_j})=1$.

Comment: Yes.Thanks a lot.